# Creating a reference raster in R

Tags: raster, r, coordinate-system

I need to create global reference raster (100km grid, Eckert IV). Later, I will project other various rasters (with different resolutions and projections) into the resolution/projection of the reference grid.

I am using the following code:

First to create a global grid in lat-long 1 degree:

```
ref_grid<-extent(-180, 180, -90, 90)
ref_grid<-raster(ref_grid)
res(ref_grid)<-1
values(ref_grid)<-1#dummy values
projection(ref_grid)<-CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs    +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0")
```

Project the reference layer into an equal area grid of 100km

```
ref_gridProj<-projectRaster(ref_grid, crs="+proj=eck4 +datum=WGS84", res=100000)
Warning message: 
In rgdal::rawTransform(projto_int, projfrom, nrow(xy), xy[, 1],  :    
3480 projected point(s) not finite
```

Later project one of my data rasters into this reference grid:

```
datalayerProj <- projectRaster(datalayer, ref_gridProj)
Warning message:
In rgdal::rawTransform(projto_int, projfrom, nrow(xy), xy[, 1],  :    
3480 projected point(s) not finite
```

My question is whether I am doing this the most efficient way and also whether I need to worry about these warning messages.

Answer (score 2):

You are using GDAL, so it should be efficient, but it is wise to be concerned about warning messages.

You appear to be using the `raster` add-on to `R`, adding some raster GIS capabilities to base `R`.  The very first thing to know about *any* raster GIS is how its logical storage of the values compares to how the programming language references those values.  The language will use a two-dimensional array, but do the columns of that array correspond to columns in the raster or rows?  A simple way to find out is to place a sequence of values into the raster, in order.  Since in this case it plots with near-horizontal stripes, we deduce the GIS lays out data along rows.  Since `R` lays matrices out in columns, this means the *columns* of a matrix correspond to *rows* of the map.

Let's study what's going on by starting with a raster that has recognizable values, such as these sequential values, and seeing what happens to them under the projection.  We get a bit of a mess, so I started over by projecting *one hemisphere at a time.*  Here are plots of the original rasters and the projections of the separate hemispheres:

[image: Figure 1]

To figure out what's going on here, it helps to understand how raster projection works.  The *source* is some raster and so is the *target*.  To project the source, each cell in the *target* is examined in turn.  The inverse of the projection is used to find the *source* point that corresponds to the center of the target cell.  Values found in this source cell (when using the nearest-neighbor method of interpolation) and values of neighbors of this source cell (when using other methods of interpolation) are used to determine what the target value should be.  That value is written in the target cell.

As a result, it is mathematically possible for *every* target cell to get a value, *even when the image of the projection is only supposed to occupy part of the raster.*  That is how in the bottom left map some values from the Western hemisphere got projected to *two or more* locations, some at the very right.  That is how in the bottom right map some values from the Eastern hemisphere were projected to the very left (in addition to their correct locations).

Although this behavior may work well for analyzing raster data, it does not correctly execute the cartographic intention: the projection is supposed to map each point on the earth to *at most one* cell in the target raster.  For cartography we usually need to mask the projection to blot out the extra junk appearing around the perimeter.

The most general way to construct a mask requires use of the projection equations.  Fortunately, we can avoid that with the Eckert IV projection by manipulating the bottom two images.  The junk appearing way to the right in the bottom left map and the junk appearing way to the left in the bottom right map show us what needs to be masked out.  With a little bit of map algebra, we can combine those two junk regions into a single mask grid.  For details, see the code below.

[image: Figure 2]

At the upper left of these figures is the mask itself: green for the projected Western hemisphere, gray for the projected Eastern hemisphere, and white for the masked areas.  At the upper right this mask has been applied to the original projection to make it a one-to-one transformation.  **That is the result you want to achieve.**

As a check of this approach, the *masked* projection was unprojected, producing the map at the lower left.  Ideally it will be exactly the same as the map we started with (in lat-lon coordinates).  It looks quite similar in this case.  But looking is not enough.  In practice the original and the "round-trip" version will differ a little due to the interpolations occurring during the projection and reprojection.  Indeed, because the Eckert IV projection is singular around its perimeter, we should expect problems to arise near the poles and the +/-180 degree meridian. This is confirmed in the final image at the lower right, which directly compares the round-trip value to the original.  The stripes of nonzero values above latitude 85N (approximately) and below 85S show the problems near the poles.  Such problems are unavoidable.  They might be slightly ameliorated using a higher resolution and a different interpolation method, but they will never entirely go away.

---

This `R` code shows how a mask can be constructed and used.

```
library(raster)
library(rgdal)
par(mfrow=c(2,2)) # Plot four figures at a time
par(mai=c(0.8466, 0.6806, 0.6806, 3*0.3486))

s.crs <- "+proj=eck4 +datum=WGS84" # Target projection
lambda <- 90                       # Maximum absolute latitude to use
resolution <- 5                    # Source resolution, degrees
resolution.projected <- 1.11e5     # Target resolution, meters
#
# Create and plot a lat-lon grid with sequential values.
#
x.r<-extent(-180, 180, -lambda, lambda)
x.r<-raster(x.r)
res(x.r)<-resolution
projection(x.r)<-CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0")

x <- 1:prod(dim(x.r)) * resolution^2 / 360 # A regular sequence of values
values(x.r) <- x
plot(x.r, main="Sequential Values", xlab="Longitude", ylab="Latitude")
#
# Identify the hemispheres with a logical grid.  Plot it.
#
m <- dim(x.r)[1]
n <- dim(x.r)[2]
hemispheres <- outer(1:m, 1:n, function(i,j) 2*j <= n)
values(x.r) <- hemispheres
plot(x.r, main="Hemispheres", xlab="Longitude", ylab="Latitude")
#
# Separately project each hemisphere.  Plot the results.
#
for (hemisphere in c(TRUE, FALSE)) {
  s <- paste(ifelse(hemisphere, "Western", "Eastern"), "Hemisphere")
  values(x.r) <- ifelse(hemispheres==hemisphere, x, NA)
  proj.r <-projectRaster(x.r, crs=s.crs, res=resolution.projected, method="ngb")
  plot(proj.r, main=paste("Projected", s), xlab="Longitude", ylab="Latitude")
}
#
# Construct a mask covering the target map.  Plot it.
#
values(x.r) <- hemispheres
proj.r <-projectRaster(x.r, crs=s.crs, res=resolution.projected, method="ngb")
m <- dim(proj.r)[1]; n <- dim(proj.r)[2]
hemispheres <- outer(1:n, 1:m, function(i,j) 2*i < n)
mask <- matrix(values(proj.r), ncol=m)
mask[hemispheres != mask] <- NA
mask <- as.vector(mask)
values(proj.r) <- mask
plot(proj.r, main="Projected Mask", xlab="Longitude", ylab="Latitude")
#
# Mask the original projection.  Plot it.
#
values(x.r) <- x
proj.r <-projectRaster(x.r, crs=s.crs, res=resolution.projected, method="ngb")
y <- values(proj.r)
y[is.na(mask)] <- NA
values(proj.r) <- y
plot(proj.r, main="Masked Projection", xlab="Longitude", ylab="Latitude")
#
# Back-project the masked projection.
# The plot should look like the original.
#
back.r <- projectRaster(proj.r, to=x.r)
plot(back.r, main="Inverse of Masked Projection", xlab="Longitude", ylab="Latitude")
#
# Plot the differences: there are problems near the poles.
#
delta.r <- back.r
values(delta.r) <- values(delta.r) - x
plot(delta.r, main="Final - Original", xlab="Longitude", ylab="Latitude")
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment! Actually I think my shorter code reaches the same end point.... but I now have a better understanding.